# exact value of $\int_0^\infty (\frac{1-{e^{-x}}}{x})^n dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found a very strange pattern when I was playing around in Wolfram Alpha, and getting it to compute
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1-{e^{-x}}}{x}\right)^n \mathbb{d}x$$
for different values of $n$. I found that for integer $n$ ($n>1$) the answer works out to be $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$ multiplied by an integer combination of $\ln(r)$ for every integer $r \le n$. Moreover, the coefficients grow very rapidly, and the coefficient of $\ln(r)$ seems to always have a large power of $r$ as a factor, yet they always manage to cancel out to produce a small answer. I don't have a particularly clear idea of the pattern, as Wolfram Alpha was unable to compute the answer for $n>8$, and Wolfram Alpha splits the composite terms, so I can't tell what the coefficients are except for primes $p$ such that $p \le n < 2p$.

I found this a very strange kind of answer, and I don't have any idea how to go about evaluating this integral. I would like to know what the pattern is, and understand why this is the answer. So I would appreciate it if someone who knows more calculus than me could give me an exact solution to the integral (and explain how to get the solution).

Comment: One approach here is to start going through tables of known definite integrals to see if this is already known. This family of definite integrals would seem to be an example of integrands which are "rational functions of powers and exponentials". However, my search of Gradshteyn and Rhyzik hasn't revealed a match yet. So far my closest candidate is (3.432.1) which gives a finite sum for $$\int_0^\infty x^{\nu-1} e^{-mx} (e^{-x}-1)^n\,\mathrm dx.$$ But this sum is only valid for $\text{Re }\nu>0$, whereas the case at hand requires $\nu=1-n< 0$ for $n>1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Integrate by parts $n-1$ times to express
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1-{e^{-x}}}{x}\right)^n {d}x
 =\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty \frac{d^{n-1} [(1-{e^{-x}})^n ]}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{dx}x
$$
which can be evaluated by expanding $(1-{e^{-x}})^n $ and integrating piecewise to arrive at
$$I_n= \frac1{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk (-1)^{n+k}k^{n-1}\ln k
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see how you convert it into your RHS integral, and $\frac{d^{n-1} [(1-{e^{-x}})^n ]}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{1}{x}$ splits into terms that look like $\frac{e^{-kx}}{x}$, but I can't see how to separate those terms in a way that the integrals converge piecewise. Please can you tell me what pieces you split it into?

Comment: @ZoeAllen - you can construct converging integrals $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}-e^{-x}}xdx$ by recognizing $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^{n-1} [(1-{e^{-x}})^n ]}{dx^{n-1}}=0$